# How to run code (change text of text view) itself if activity is created (visible)?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I searched a lot and tried it with handler but nothing worked..

I want an activity with a text view (remove text in on create) and if its visible I want to set text to this view and after some times again and again and again..

Do I really need an interaction from user like button to start this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using a Handler that runs a Runnable that calls itself again after some time.

So, you can declare a Handler and a Runnable like so

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mTextView.setText("wtv");
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

So, onCreate you clear the textview and start the runnable

```
mTextView.setText("");

mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
```

Comment: Post some code and any exceptions you get if it doesn't work.

Comment: had a silly mistake on an other place - you can't cast tv.getText to String→you have to add "" after the line..

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
static int i = 0;
final int MAX_COUNT = 10;
final int TIME_DELAY = 5000;
final TextView textView = %yours text view%;
final Runnable changeTextViewState = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    textView.setText("it" + i++);
    if (i < MAX_COUNT) {
        textView.postDelayed(this, TIME_DELAY);
    }
  }
};
textView.postDelayed(changeTextViewState, TIME_DELAY);
```